# Selecting a range in Excel based on values in a different column

Tags: excel, select, range

I'm not exactly sure how to name what I need.

I have data in columns B and C starting from cells B2 and C2(row 1 is a header row). The data in these two columns are copied by me from a text document and the amount of values can vary. In columns E, G, H, L, M, N there are formulas which work off the data supplied in columns B and C. I need to be able to copy the formulas which exist in the second row of each column and have it fit to the amount of data that is populated in columns B and C. From there, I would like to copy the values that are calculated in columns L, M, N and paste them in columns Q, R, S and sort from smallest to largest.

I have started some code which contains a selection of the data in columns B(copied from txt file) and conducts a text-to-columns process on it.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("b2", ActiveSheet.Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(10, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("A1:D1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
```

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. The data in Column C is populated after the text to columns on column b.

Comment: B and C will be the same "height", but like I said earlier that "height" will change depending on the data available to me. Thanks for the assistance by the way! :)

Comment: L, M & N can stay as they are, I'm copying the values out into Q R & S where it will be sorted as a group from smallest to largest based on the values in column R. Hope that made sense..